# Installation problem with kinect

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I am new to ROS/Ubuntu and hoping someone could shed some light into my problem.

My main problem is that I cannot see any result of depth and RGB from Kinect, even though I installed following instructions introduced from http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect.

Below is what I have done so far:

1. I have installed openni_kinect (electric); "sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect "
2. unplug and plug in the Kinect.
3. type command "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch."

```
 ** result image shown:[link image](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxupHPuhFy-HOWUxNjEwZTktMTBiMy00OTIxLTg4ZjQtNDhiOTE2YjQ5N2Yw)
```

As you can see from the image description, it seems the above command has registered kinetic

4. when I run "rosrun rviz rviz", it does not show anything except black screen so far. Is there anything specific I should be doing to RVIZ to get the kinetic camera to capture?

Thanks for you help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12587/installation-problem-with-kinect/) by [Jong H Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1617/jong-h-kim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you add a Pointcloud2 display and choose a topic?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-01-11**:
Please mark your question as answered, if the given answers satisfy your needs.

**Comment by [Jong H Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1617/jong-h-kim/) on 2012-01-11**:
Thank you it also worked. i now can see colorful picture. I really appreciate that :D

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-01-10**:
You need to subscribe the appropriate topic. One is named rgb one depth iirc. Also select color transformer RGB8.

**Comment by [Jong H Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1617/jong-h-kim/) on 2012-01-10**:
Thank you so much. I did as you mentioned. It worked. I really appreciate that. I have another question. RVIZ screen shows only black and white colors. Is there any way to get RGB with depth and how can I see 3D pictures. Thanks.